# Should we reverse the duplication of these questions about simultaneous readied actions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

[What happens when 2 readied actions trigger at the same time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131700/what-happens-when-2-readied-actions-trigger-at-the-same-time) the more recent question has been marked as a duplicate of [How are simultaneously-triggered Readied actions resolved?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68925/how-are-simultaneously-triggered-readied-actions-resolved).

However, I think the older question (the current dupe target) is flawed in a few ways that might make switching the duplicates to be helpful.

1. The premise of the question is flawed in that it need not use Readied actions at all to accomplish the goal. This makes it not a great candidate for a question about the topic and allows the true answer to the question to avoid answering the overall question.
2. None of the answers cite text as evidence (despite the top answer being highly rated).

Full disclosure: I have an answer on the closed question, but that has no bearing on why I think the newer question is better.

I could put a bounty on the current dupe target to improve the answers, but nothing can be done about the question itself.

It could be argued that since the one question deals with attacks and the other with spells that they could be not duplicates at all, but I think they are close enough that they might best be still marked as duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

## I don’t think either should be a duplicate of the other

The older question should, I think, be edited so the title is more specific to the specific case asked about, because that specific case is what was actually answered, and then we have two distinct question: one about a specific case where someone *thought* they needed to know how to handle simultaneous readied actions, but actually didn’t, and one that just directly asks about simultaneous readied actions. In other words, the first question ended up being treated as an X-Y problem, and since the problem *actually wasn’t* X, it isn’t really a dupe of a question about X.